# ddrescue - retry bad sectors starting from the end of the disk

Tags: data-recovery, bad-blocks, dynamic-disk, ddrescue

How can I attempt to read bad sectors from the end of the disk, using ddrescue?
I have dynamic volumes and the LDR is kept at the end of the disk, unlike MBR.

I remember that I've tried `--reverse` but it changed the direction from the last tried position(basically going back towards the starting point, from the first bad sectors found), instead of starting from the end of the disk.